# How do I set the value of a select field to a parameter after a JQuery function has been called?

Tags: php, select

I have a page with tasks that can be edited. This is the Ajax function that first gets called to fill in the first select field with those tasks:

```js
function prikazi(zadatak) {

  if (zadatak == "") {
    $("#skriveno").css('display', 'none');
  } else {
    $("#skriveno").css('display', 'flex');
  }
}
prikazi("");

function popuniDetalje() {
  let zadatak = $("#zadatak").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "../funkcije/vratiPodatke.php",
    data: {
      zadatak: zadatak,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#skriveno").html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="containerwrapper">
  <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="container_unos">
    <h4>Zadatak</h4>
    <select id="zadatak" name="zadatak" onchange="prikazi(this.value); popuniDetalje();" required></select>

    <div id="skriveno" name="skriveno" class="skriveno">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

When I call the popuniDetalje( ) function I make new fields visible and I fill it up with the task's data that can now be edited before updated. This is what the vratiPodatke.php file looks like:

```
<?php
require "../konekcija/konekcija.php";
require "../modeli/zadatak.php";

$zadatak = trim($_GET["zadatak"]);

$podaci = Zadatak::vratiPodatke($zadatak, $konekcija);

?>

<h4>Naziv</h4>
<input type="text" id="naziv" name="naziv" class="input" value = <?=$podaci->naziv?> autocomplete="off">


<h4>Kategorija</h4>
<select id="kategorija" name="kategorija"></select>

<h4>Opis</h4>
<textarea name="opis" id="opis"><?=$podaci->opis?></textarea>

<script>
    function popuniKategorije() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../funkcije/popuniKategorije.php',
            success: function (data) {
               $("#kategorija").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    popuniKategorije();

    function postaviVrednost() {
        $("#kategorija").val("<?= $podaci->kategorija ?>").change();
    }
    postaviVrednost();
</script>
```

Getting the data works fine and the fields `naziv` and `opis`  get filled properly. When I call the function `popuniKategorije()` it works well with filling the categories. This is what popuniKategorije.php looks like:

```
<?php
require "../konekcija/konekcija.php";
require "../modeli/kategorija.php";

$kategorije = Kategorija::vratiKategorije($konekcija);

?>
<option value="" disabled selected hidden><?= "Kategorija zadatka" ?> </option>
<?php

foreach ($kategorije as $kat) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?= $kat->kategorijaID ?>"><?= $kat->nazivKategorije ?> </option>
    <?php
}
?>
```

This works fine, but when I want to call the function `postaviVrednost()`  to set the option that correlates to the value I got from the database, it doesn't work and it acts like the function is not there, i.e. just fills up the categories as if none have been picked. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. You're calling `postaviVrednost();` before the async operation has completed. You should call it in the `success:` function of `popuniKategorije()` after the `.html()` call.

Comment: Ah that was the problem, I didn't realize what I was doing. Thank you so much!